# C++ Simple Decrement Using Pointers (puzzled)

Tags: c++

Im a little puzzled about this behaviour. Can Anyone Explain

```
  void Decrement(int* x){
        *x--; //using this line, the output is 5 

        //*x=*x-1; //using this l ine, the output is 4

    }

    int main(){
        int myInt=5;
        Decrement(&myInt);
        cout<<myInt<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    Output: 5
```

Comment: Just for the record: use references, not pointers!

Comment: @doomster: that's a personal preference. I don't like non-const references. I like seeing the & at the call site which makes it clear that the value will be modified.

Comment: This has to be a dupe, right?

Comment: I was learning about pointers, hence, the use of pointers. I know it can be done by reference but I was playing around with pointers.

Comment: Actually, I understand that the "&" makes it clear what's going on. C# adds a keyword to document that you are intentionally passing in a reference. Concerning the rationale for my choice, I prefer references because it makes clear that they must not be null, which is always a question with pointers. That said, this code should look like `int const myInt = prev(5);`, i.e. use the return value when it has to return something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*x--` means `*(x--)`.  That is, your program modifies `x`, not what it points to.  Since it's passed by value, that modification has no effect in `main()`.  To match your commented line, you'd need to use `(*x)--`.

Comment: It appears that on another question, you commented “Why is it undefined? He never dereferences the bad pointer. Is simply creating it bad enough?”. `x--` is indeed undefined if `x` is a pointer to the very beginning of an object. In C++, the reason is in 5.7:5.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: No, it is not. Incrementing or decrementing a pointer (to an array) beyond its end doesn't invoke undefined behavior. Only *dereferencing* does. That is, `int a[10]; int *p = a + 100; ++p; p--; p+=100;` is perfectly fine. It invokes UB only if you attempt to dereference `p`. So `*p` or `p[0]` is UB.

Comment: It might very well be UB in the strictest sense.  I'm having a hard time coming up with an example where it would be a problem, though.

Comment: @Nawaz n1905, 5.7:7, “… otherwise, the behavior is undefined.” I provided the reference the first time. Did you look at it before commenting?

Comment: @PascalCuoq, do you have an example of how said undefined behaviour could affect the operation of a program?  Any real-world example will do.  I'm just not coming up with anything, at least based on implementations I know anything about.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yes, I just read it *"[...] If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."* I don't think it says what you said. (I quoted from n3485).

Comment: @CarlNorum Real world example with real consequences, in C, of the fact that `p+100` is undefined behavior: http://lwn.net/Articles/278137/

Comment: @PascalCuoq: C and C++ are different languages; please don't mix both in the same discussion. It adds confusion to one's understanding of either language.

Comment: @Nawaz This is why I referred to the wording of the C++ standard regarding pointer arithmetic, but since we have agreed to disagree on what “otherwise the behavior is undefined” means, there is nothing I can add. I have no doubt that p+100 < p is true in C++ for some values of p, and that the explanation for this behavior, were you to ask the developers of the C++ compiler, is that p+100 is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I thought about it again. I think you're right. It particularly violates *"or one past the last element of the array object"*. Thanks for pointing this intricacy of the pointer arithmetic in C++. :-) (which means I was *accidently* right in my answer :P but then I think **CarlNorum** will add this to his answer :). )

Comment: @PascalCuoq, thanks for the link.  I still don't see how anything bad would happen until the errant pointer was dereferenced, though.  Clearly creating a bad pointer and then *using* it is bad news.  What I'm trying to understand is how the simple act of *creating* the bad pointer can affect anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try `(*x)--;`.

Your code is decrementing the pointer, then dereferencing that and discarding the value.

Answer (score 2):

This is an operator precedence problem.

The `--` operator is taking precedence over the dereference operator (`*`). Therefore what you're actually doing is merely accessing the value at one memory location below the location of x (and doing nothing with it).

What I sense you probably want to do is to pass x "by reference". That would look like this:

```
void Decrement(int& x){
    x--;
}

int main(){
    int myInt = 5;
    Decrement(myInt);
    cout << myInt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When you pass a value by reference, C++ automatically dereferences the pointer for you, which is why the `*` is no longer needed in the Decrement function.

Comment: @qPCR4vir Ah sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting (*x)-- and are getting *(x--). The reason is [Precedence of Operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Look it up. pre and post increment bind before "dereference address".

Answer (score 2):

You are basically passing a pointer `x` by value. As a result of which changes on `x` (and not in what it point to) in the `void Decrement(int*)` function doesn't reflect in the `main()`. This code will achieve what you intended to do:

```
void Decrement(int& x)
    {
        x--;

    }

int main()
    {
        int myInt=5;
        Decrement(myInt);
        cout<<myInt<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    Output: 4
```

This is call by reference by which the reference(or address) to the variable is passed.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `*x--` is equivalent to `*(x--)`.